# Find and remove by Id a subdocument in array with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete a subdocuments in array with Mongoose.

My datas :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb762"
    },
    "spaces": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76f"
        },
        "name": "Building 2",
        "subSpace": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771"
            },
            "name": "Basement"
        }, {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb770"
            },
            "name": "Floors"
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76c"
        },
        "name": "Building 4",
        "subSpace": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76e"
            },
            "name": "Basement"
        }, {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76d"
            },
            "name": "Floors"
        }]
    }]
}
```

For this example, we want to delete the subSpace **Floors** in **Building 2** with this _id : *5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771*

My code (in the model) :

```js
exports.removeSubSpaceById = (subSpaceId) => {
    Residence.findOneAndUpdate( { "spaces.subSpace._id": '5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771' },
        { $pull: 
        { spaces: 
        { subSpace: 
        { _id: '5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771' }}}}, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
    })
};
```

Output : console.log : my entire document
But the subSpace/Basement (*5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771*) is still in my document.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positional operator for nested array operations. [MongoDb Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
exports.removeSubSpaceById = (subSpaceId) => {
Residence.findOneAndUpdate({ "spaces._id": '5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76f' },
    {
        $pull:
        {
            "spaces.$.subSpace": { _id: "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771" }
        }
    }, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
```

}